# Почему wordpress выводит только 6 последних постов?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывожу посты таким образом. По какой-то причине выводится только последних 6, и так не в одной категории, а во всех, максимум выводит 6 постов. В чем может быть проблема?

```html
<?php
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'category_name'    => 'clients',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'numberposts' => 100,
) );

foreach( $posts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    
?>
    <div class="client_col__wrap col-xl-2 col-md-3">
        <div class="client_col"><img class="client_img" src="<?php the_field('client_logo') ?>" alt="">
            <p class="client_col__text"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
?>
```

UPD, попробовал еще вот так(по советам из комментариев):

```html
<?php

global $post;


$mypost = get_posts( array(
    'category_name'    => 'clients',
     'post_type'   => 'post',
     'numberposts' => 100,
) );
                    
foreach( $mypost as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
                        
?>

    <div class="client_col__wrap col-xl-2 col-md-3">
        <div class="client_col"><img class="client_img" src="<?php the_field('client_logo') ?>" alt="">
            <p class="client_col__text"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php
}
                    
wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс

?>
```

Это не помогло, разве что теперь вывелись другие 6 постов, не те, что были до этого

Comment: Проверьте, не используется ли где-то в теме или плагинах хук `pre_get_posts` для изменения устанавливаемого количества записей в запросах

Comment: @alenkins, как это можно проверить?

Comment: вангую: шаблон с этим кодом не подключается, а *6* - задано в настройках ВП.

Comment: Аааа... **posts** - [зарезервированный термин](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) А $post не объявлен глобальным

Comment: @SeVlad, можете пожалуйста по простому сказать, что нужно сделать?

Comment: добавить в начале global $post (вне цикла). а $posts переименовать в $myposts, к примеру.

Comment: @Алексей, сделал, как Вы сказали, но это не помогло, разве что посты почему то вывелись не самые последние, а обычно 6 последних выводило prntscr.com/ogq2h5

Comment: Отключите все плагины, тема самописная? Смотрите в ней хук `pre_get_posts`. Уберите пока `category_name`. Попробуйте просто посты вывести, замените число в numberposts на -1. Или вместо numberposts используйте `posts_per_page`. Тут сложно сказать, в таких случаях нужно дебажить и смотреть что не так.